# Combining convolutional layers and LSTM layers with variable-length sequences

Tags: machine-learning, keras, convolution, lstm

I am trying to combine Conv2D layers with LSTM layers on images.
The problem is that the Conv2D layers takes as input a 4D tensor including the number of channels, and my LSTM network needs a 3D tensor.

The problem is that I use bucketing, so my inputs don't have a predefined number of timesteps. I wanted to do something like that :

```
input_data = Input(shape=[None, nb_features, 1])
cnn1 = Conv2D(nb_filters, kernel_size)(input_data)
cnn2 = Conv2D(nb_filters, kernel_size)(cnn1)
reshape = Reshape(target_shape=[None, nb_features])(cnn2)
gru1 = Bidirectional(GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True))(reshape)
gru2 = Bidirectional(GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True))(gru1)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(nblabels))(gru2)
output = Activation('softmax')(out)
```

But the Reshape layer needs a fully defined shape. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What is "nb_features"? Are you sure you want a Conv2D (Ex: 2D image) instead of a Conv1D (Ex: some var in time)? --- PS: don't use "None" in the shapes, and use tuples `(nb_features,1)` instead of lists.

Comment: In this case, nb_features will be the height of my images, which will be constant. And I am sure I want a Conv2D on the whole image and not a TimeDistributed Conv1D. The reason I use None is because I need the length of my sequence to be variable.

Comment: I don't mean a TimeDistributed Conv1D, I mean just a conv1D.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is that you use:

```
input_data = Input((None, nb_features))
cnn1 = Conv1D(nb_filters, kernel_size)(input_data)
cnn2 = Conv1D(nb_filters, kernel_size)(cnn1)

gru1 = Bidirectional(GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True))(cnn2)
gru2 = Bidirectional(GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True))(gru1)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(nblabels))(gru2)
output = Activation('softmax')(out)
```

Then you can either use a [Masking Layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) at the beginning (and pad your input data with a dummy value), or you can use many numpy batches, each batch with a different length, without a masking or padding.